# Nightwatch does not create html report , If there is any run-time failure in nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am using this module -https://bl.ocks.org/denji/204690bf21ef65ac7778 to create html report for my nightwatch test. Test report creates successfully if there is no run-time error during the test run. for an example it creates html report successfully even if one of the assertion fail, as long as there is no run-time error.

however if there is any error thrown like below then , it does not create html report including all the test suites it ran.(please check the screen-shot i've attached as well).  How can i capture all the failures in the html-report and create the report successfully.

````
    POST  /wd/hub/session/fd34aff5c708035939c98efd74afd866/elements - ECONNRESET
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:570:14)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:380:25)
 Error while running .locateMultipleElements() protocol action: An unknown error has occurred.```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgOat.png
````

Comment: Socket hangup is something completely unrecoverable and out of nightwatch's control. It has been happening for a while. Maybe you should report this on their github repository. I remember there are issues opened already for this. Please check those before opening new one.

Comment: @Raju, my actual issue is how to make the report stable. End of the day for what ever reason if test fails, i want that failure in my report. its not about this particular issue. I was able to resolve that failure by increasing the timeout as per this issue - `https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1936`. If you can suggest better reporting module please do so with some sample configuration. so that i can refer to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about html-report. Its about junit xml report. The junit xml report is not generated when the element is not found. https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1977. 
I was using the version nightwatch 1.3.2. Better solution is to update to the latest version 1.3.4